# Get Value From dropdownlist filled from another dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two dropdownlists. 1st: `ddlProvince` - 2nd:`ddlCities`.

I filled `ddlProvince` with following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        dtProvince = clsD.FillDataTable("provinceFetch");//Get data using stored procedure
        ddlProvince.DataSource = dtProvince;
        ddlProvince.DataTextField = "pName";
        ddlProvince.DataValueField = "pId";
        ddlProvince.DataBind();
    }
}
```

and for populating `ddlCities` use following code in `Page_Load` :

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
    ddlCity.DataSource = geo.getCities(ddlProvince.SelectedValue.ToString());
    ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
    ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityId";
    ddlCity.DataBind();
}
```

Both dropdownlists works fine but I can only get first value from `ddlCities` when I click on button. And `ddlCities` index will reset to 0 after post back.

I know button sends a post back, but `ddlCities` get its data on postback too.

This is my aspx markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/UserAuthentication/Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Register" EnableViewState="true" %>
<body>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" runat="server">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="country" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Province</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProvince" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <label for="country" class="col-sm-3 control-label">City</label>
           <div class="col-sm-9">
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="true"></asp:DropDownList>
           </div>
       </div>
       <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" OnClick="btnRegister_ServerClick" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block login-button" Text="Register" />
    </form>
</body>
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you populate the ddlCity on the SelectedIndexChanged of the ddlProvinces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you don't use Page_load to load ddlCities. Instead use the event on ddlProvince. There is a lot of ways to to this:

Code Behind:

```
protected void itemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlCity.DataSource = geo.getCities(ddlProvince.SelectedValue.ToString());
    ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
    ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityId";
    ddlCity.DataBind();
}
```

On your aspx file:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProvince" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="itemSelected"></asp:DropDownList>
```

There is one or other adjustment on your code but this can do the job!